# Object is not iterable issue

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am getting "object is not iterable" error in my flask application that deployed httpd.

```
def createTable(self, table_name, values):
    print('IN CREATE TABLE')
    cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        """
        CREATE TABLE {table_name} ({values})
        """.format(table_name=table_name, values=values)
    )
    self.conn.commit()
    print('OUT CREATE TABLE')
```

First print that include IN CREATE TABLE printed out but secont print is not printed. So, there is a problem in create table but i cant see.

```
mod_wsgi (pid=13470): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ec2-user/master/app.wsgi'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 870, in __next__
     return self._next()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 82, in _iter_encoded
     for item in iterable:
 TypeError: 'OperationalError' object is not iterable
```

And I am getting this error.

Comment: I don't think your error is coming from the createTable function. Also, you may want to look at other ways to create tables. str.format() opens you up to sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you are passing `values` into `createTable` as some sort of iterable. I would remove the paranthesis around `({values})` and use the following for `format`:

```
"""
CREATE TABLE {table_name} {values}
""".format(table_name=table_name, values=tuple(values) if len(values) > 1 else "({})".format(values[0]))
```

So breaking down `values=tuple(values) if len(values) > 1 else "({})".format(values[0])` we have

`tuple(values)`:

When creating a table in sqlite, the column names need to have a parenthesis around them so I usually use a tuple type to enforce this in the `format` for a print statement. The `tuple(values)` ensures that whatever type of iterable `values` is (like a list for example), it will be converted to a tuple iterable.

`if len(values) > 1`:

You should only use `tuple(values)` when the `values` that is passed in has more than one element in it. Otherwise the SQL that will be executed will be something like

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_name (col_1,)
```

Which would cause the sqlite to complain with that comma without a second column value.

`else "({})".format(values[0])`:

Otherwise if `values` only has a single element, index it and place it in the parenthesis explicitly in the string.

Comment: I tried but still getting same error :( I am running locally and working very well but in httpd, it is not working

Comment: Are you able to print the SQL string that's being created both locally and httpd then compare?

Comment: Yes i can print locally sql string. However i converted the app to use ORM :) And works well :) thanks a lot.